# How do I rename multiple tags in TFS

Tags: tfs, tags, renaming

I am using TFS 2017-R3.  I am needing to rename some tags.  I am looking for the process to change the tags in quantity not one at a time.

Comment: Which tag are you talking about? Work item tags, Git tags, or build Tags?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the work item tags, then you can follow below ways to rename the tags:

**1** - If you have **Visual Studio** as the client, then you can use
   the VS extension to rename the tags.

VS 2015 : [Tag Admin for Visual Studio 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UtkarshShigihalliandTarunArora.TagAdminforVisualStudio2015)

VS 2017 : [Tag Admin for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UtkarshShigihalliandTarunArora.TagAdminforVisualStudio2017)

[image]

**2** - Upgrade to TFS 2018, then install the TFS
   extension [Tags Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YodLabs.TagsManager2)(it only supports TFS 2018 and VSTS for
   now) to rename the tags.

[image]

**3** - Rename the tags with REST API:

```
PATCH http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/Tagging/scopes/{ProjectID}/tags/{TagID}?api-version=1.0

Content-Type: application/json

{"name":"LC0425Update3","active":true}
```

You can use below REST API to get the project ID：

`http://SERVER:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/projects/{ProjectName}`

[image]

**Thus the tags on all the work items will be updated accordingly once they are renamed.**

---

Besides, you can also create a query which include the tags column and export the work items to Excel, then bulk edit/rename the Tags in excel, then publish back to TFS. See [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=vsts) for details.

Comment: @Russ Have you resolved the issue by above answer? any update?

Answer (score 0):

When you upgrade to TFS 2018 or use VSTS an alternative is the Tags Manager https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=YodLabs.TagsManager2 which can take care of your work item tags.

It will be installed in TFS/VSTS Work tab and allows to rename, delete and merge tags.